# Change artifact version in runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project which has a certain dependency versioned through properties, i.e.:

```
<properties>
  <version.example-artifact>1.0.0</version.example-artifact>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${version.example-artifact}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have multiple minor versions of this artifact:

```
1.0.0
1.1.0
```

They are API-compatible, so the rest of the code can be compiled against one and run without recompilation against the other.

From command line, I can do this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dversion.example-artifact=1.1.0 ...
```

to change the artifact version when running the project.

Is something like that possible in Eclipse in debug / run configurations only? Specifically, I'd like to avoid changing the pom. I've tried adding:

```
-Dversion.example-artifact=1.1.0
```

to VM arguments, but "Show command line" says it's still using the artifact version defined in pom.xml (i.e. 1.0.0).

Comment: Your Eclipse run config is presumably not invoking maven. Is that right? It's just running the code directly?

Comment: @Michael Yeah the command line in "Show command line" looks to be generated by Eclipse and just runs `java`, not `mvn`. I assume that's just using `maven` (the one built in into Eclipse) underneath to get the command line to execute, so I am looking to see if there's a way to influence that command line somehow to get the same effect as when running `mvn` from the command line.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Eclipse. IntelliJ has a specific run config type for maven though. You should be using the equivalent, if such a thing exists